# How to specify destination directory in Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, config

I cant find an example that shows how to specify a directory in Config.groovy which will be called in any part of the application. The said directory will serve as a repository for the  files that will be generated by the application.

Any help from you guys will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to specify a config option in `Config.groovy` to hold a path to a directory which in turn will be used to store files. Obviously adding it to `Config.groovy` isn't a problem, so your question is: "How do I access items in `Config.groovy`" ????

Comment: actually, the problems are: How to add it in Config.groovy and How to access it somewhere in the application like in a Service or in a Job. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following in Config.groovy:

```
my.app.location="/Some/Path"
```

You can access this via the injectable grailsApplication like so:

```
def SomeController {

  def grailsApplication

  def someAction() {
    def location = grailsApplication.config.my.app.location
  }
}
```

Same applies to Services, Taglibs, etc.

Comment: ohh thanks! this perfectly works..will this be applicable on the test and production environment?